# MVC application throws error when opening dev tools in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm catching an error in my Application_Error method in global.asax when opening the dev tools in my browser.  It's happening in both Chrome and IE (haven't tried any other browsers).  This just started happening.  The error is **"The controller for path '/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js.map' was not found or does not implement IController."**.

I'm getting the same error for different files.

1. The controller for path '/Content/kendo.common.min.css.map' was not found or does not implement IController.
2. The controller for path '/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js.map' was not found or does not implement IController.
3. The controller for path '/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js.map' was not found or does not implement IController.
4. The controller for path '/Scripts/kendo.timezones.min.js.map' was not found or does not implement IController.
5. The controller for path '/Content/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css.map' was not found or does not implement IController.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and Kendo v2018.1.117.  No idea why all of a sudden this started happening.  The error is thrown multiple times.  My application launches fine, but when I try to open the dev tools to debug a javascript function from one of m views, it blows up.  It also blows up when I open the dev tools from my Home view - which isn't anything fancy.  Only seems to happen with the Kendo files for some reason.  I've compared this project to another project I'm working on that are very similar and can't find any difference that might point to the cause of this.

Any ideas?

Here's the stack trace:

```
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

EDIT:
Here's my bundle config

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
            "~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/kendo.timezones.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo-css").Include(
            "~/Content/kendo.common.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo.bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/kendo.fixes.css"));

        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Kendo V1? How are you linking to the scripts or bundling? What version of jquery?

Comment: Kendo version is 2017.1.223.  JQuery version  is 3.3.1.  I'm bundling my scripts and pulling them into my layout view using Razor 
 i.e. Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")

Comment: Show your bundle code. There are some known issues with naming your bundle that same as a subfolder.

Comment: I edited my question to include my bundle config

Comment: Have you tried locating file "kendo.all.min.js.map" and putting it in the Scripts folder? "map" files are a convention to allow for more readable code during javascript debugging (which is part of what the DevTools do).

Comment: @PeterB For whatever reason, I don't have the map files for any of my kendo files.  I checked another similar project I'm working on (that is working fine) and there are no map files for the Kendo scripts in there either.

Comment: Technically, 3.3.1 is not compatible. See [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites). Doubt that is your problem. I would consider getting a clean version of the scripts and styles and bundling as they recommend [here](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/fundamentals#css-bundling).

Comment: @SteveGreene  I grabbed jquery v3.1.1 just to see if it made any difference, and as expected - no difference.